# Preventing all the process to print to console expect the configuration wizard process

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I have a board which has ArchLinux installed in it. My task is to create a configuration wizard which shows up when the device is booted up for the first time asking for inputs like setting date, time, customer information from the user. The board has a serial console /dev/ttyS0 and an ethernet port. I want my configuration wizard to display in serial console, ArchLinux uses systemd, so I wrote a service file for that

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple interactive dialog window
After=getty@ttyS0.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/configuration_wizard.sh
StandardInput=tty-force
TTYPath=/dev/ttyS0
TTYReset=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This service starts well and it forces to take the console and it prints to the console properly. But that other process also starts and they prints to console as well. So the console got messed up. How can I prevent other process from printing to the console?. Is there a way in .service file to stop other services like login service until the wizard completes?